# YUI Uploader: automatically open browse dialog

Tags: javascript, upload, yui

I'm using the YUI Uploader component and want to automatically open the browse dialog on page load so the user can choose a file without first clicking the upload button. Is this possible?

The uploader component is a Flash movie so I don't think it's possible to trigger a click on the upload button using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because since Flash 10, the upload browser can only be shown when a user explicitly click on the browse button

(this a security issue: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes_02.html#head3)